# Is there a way to create a variable that doesn't reset during multiple loops?

Tags: python, function, variables

I've recently been trying to write a code where I'm trying to find how many times a function returns 1.

```
fin=open("gymnastics.in", 'r')
p=(fin.readline().split())
n=int("".join(map(str, p)))
rank=[]
for i in range(3):
    line=fin.readline().strip().split()
    rank.append([int(num) for num in line])
print(rank[1])

def good_pair(cow1, cow2):
    global x
    x=0
    for i in range(3):
        if rank[0].index(cow1)<rank[0].index(cow2) and rank[1].index(cow1)<rank[1].index(cow2) and rank[2].index(cow1)<rank[2].index(cow2):
            return 0
        elif rank[0].index(cow1)>rank[0].index(cow2) and rank[1].index(cow1)>rank[1].index(cow2) and rank[2].index(cow1)>rank[2].index(cow2):
            x=x+1
            return x
        else:
            return 0


print(good_pair(4, 3))
print(good_pair(4, 2))
print(good_pair(4, 1))
print(good_pair(3, 2))
print(good_pair(3, 1))
print(good_pair(2, 1))
print(good_pair(3, 4))
print(good_pair(2, 4))
print(good_pair(1, 4))
print(good_pair(2, 3))
print(good_pair(1, 3))
print(good_pair(1, 2))
```

here I have x as the variable, but each time I call the function, the value of x gets reset. Is there a way I can have it not reset and continue to add?

Comment: The variable `x` is being reset every time you call the function because you put `x=0` into the function. Move the initialization __out of__ the function and it won't get reset every time

Comment: Define it once *before* you call your functions.

Comment: Declare `x = 0` before the function scope

Comment: Put it before the first call to `good_pair()`

Comment: It would help to write a simpler example. We don't have gymnastics.in so can't run the code. But since the file processing isn't really part of the question, a simpler example with fewer lines would be easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It doesn't reset anymore!

Comment: Please provide an example of the input file `gymnastics.in`, see [mcve] for more information

Comment: 3 4
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2
4 2 1 3
Here is an example of the input file, although the maximum number may fluxuate.

Comment: Why is the first line of the input file not used? (variables `p` and `n` are not used for anything) ?

Comment: I did not use p and n because I originally was going to, but found that using the number 3 in the loop would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You want to save state. One way to do that is to add a parameter to the function to pass in a value for `x`. On the first call, use the default. On future calls, use the last value returned. This usually better than just using a global variable because other bits of your code can use the same function without interfering with each other.

```
def good_pair(cow1, cow2, x=0):
    for i in range(3):
        if rank[0].index(cow1)<rank[0].index(cow2) and rank[1].index(cow1)<rank[1].index(cow2) and rank[2].index(cow1)<rank[2].index(cow2):
            return 0
        elif rank[0].index(cow1)>rank[0].index(cow2) and rank[1].index(cow1)>rank[1].index(cow2) and rank[2].index(cow1)>rank[2].index(cow2):
            x=x+1
            return x
        else:
            return 0

foo = good_pair(4, 3)
print(foo)
foo = good_pair(4, 2, foo)
print(foo)
```

Classes are a great way to hold state. You could change this to a class that keeps the value of `x` for you.

```
class GoodPair:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        
    def __call__(self, cow1, cow2):
        for i in range(3):
            if rank[0].index(cow1)<rank[0].index(cow2) and rank[1].index(cow1)<rank[1].index(cow2) and rank[2].index(cow1)<rank[2].index(cow2):
                return 0
            elif rank[0].index(cow1)>rank[0].index(cow2) and rank[1].index(cow1)>rank[1].index(cow2) and rank[2].index(cow1)>rank[2].index(cow2):
                self.x += 1
                return self.x
            else:
                return 0

good_pair = GoodPair()
print(good_pair(4, 3))
print(good_pair(4, 2))
```

The `__call__` method is used when you treat the class instance as a function.